# Enumerate over nested form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

Ok, I have a huge trouble finding the words to explain my problem. I hope you can understand and help me because frankly, I am going insane.

Let's say I have four models: `User`, `Team`, `Report` and `UserReport`. I have this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :user_reports
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_reports
end
class UserReport < ActiveRecort::Base
  belongs_to :report
end

class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @team = Team.find params[:team_id]
    @report = Report.new
    @team.users.each do |user|
      ur = @report.user_reports.build
      ur.user_id = user.id
    end
  end
end
```

What I have now is that the user of the site chooses the `Team`. In the team are, of course, a bunch of `User`s. For each of them, a `UserReport` is to be added to the `Report`. In the `new.html.haml`, I would write this:

```
=fields_for :user_reports do |b|
  =b.hidden_field :user_id, user.id
  =user.name
```

And there is the problem. How can I get the `user.name` or the `user.id` or anything in this form builder? I need to output the user name there, because otherwise the site user wouldn't be able to know which is who.

I do hope you understood my problem, I'm kind of desperate by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @team = Team.find params[:team_id]
    @report = Report.new
    @urs = []
    @team.users.each do |user|
      ur = @report.user_reports.build
      ur.user_id = user.id
      @urs << ur
    end
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
= form_for @report do |f|
  =f.fields_for :user_reports, @urs do |b|
    =b.hidden_field :user_id
    =b.object.user.name
```